# Is the logic of jQuery DataTable server side integration resource expensive?

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

Those who have experience with DataTables may have already known that, to make the client-side pagination work properly, jQuery DataTable required two parameters: `recordsTotal` & `records filtered`. Now this `recordsFiltered` is expecting the total number of filtered records without the pagination `LIMIT`.

Which in other words means that I have to run a query without the `LIMIT` keyword and get the count of the number of rows in that result. Then I have to execute the same query with `LIMIT` keyword to fetch the actual data. So, technically I just wrote two queries right now, one with LIMIT and one without LIMIT and executed both (However, first one just took the number of rows instead of the whole result).

Is this efficient?

I am using jQuery - HTML - PHP without any framework or ORM.

Answer (score 0):

No, the first query can just be a count query which doesn't retrieve all of the rows...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS recordsTotal from table
```